# IE9 textangular issue

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm receiving the following textangular error in IE9 or below.

```
unable to get the value of the property 'match': object is null or undefined textangular.js line 107 character 3
```

Here is the block of code that causes the error:

```
if(_browserDetect.ie > 8 || _browserDetect.ie === undefined){
var _sheets = document.styleSheets;
/* istanbul ignore next: preference for stylesheet loaded externally */
for(var i = 0; i < _sheets.length; i++){
    if(_sheets[i].media.length === 0 || _sheets[i].media.mediaText.match(/(all|screen)/ig)){
        if(_sheets[i].href){
            if(_sheets[i].href.match(/textangular\.(min\.|)css/ig)){
                sheet = _sheets[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Line 107 is starts the first `if` block

TextAngular works correctly without error in all other browsers, just IE9 and below is returning the above error.

Comment: doubt you'll get much help for support for IE8 considering angular isn't supporting it any more